# no even thickness with solidify modifier

Tags: modeling

i tryied to add thickness to this and i set the clamp to 2.0000, and i notice that i get even thickness but the thickness value doesnt does anything in a high value, i want more depth with a even thinkness, how can i do this?

capture showing how it normaly add thinkness and this how i want it of depth but with even thickness [image] capture showing how it adds even thinkness when i set clamp to 2.0000 but i cant add depth [image]

Comment: Try to check "Even thickness" in Solidify modifier.

Comment: @cgslav nope it doesnt does anything